# Error in installing cloudera search

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I have installed Cloudera search using installation guide available on the site. But when I am creating collection it’s giving me proxy authorization error as.

**Error: A call to SolrCloud WEB APIs failed: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required**

Can anyone suggest me what can be the problem?

Thanks and Regards